# Python library which allows me to add text on top of images

Tags: python, image, image-processing

do you know if there is a Python image library which allows me to add text on top of images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on google: "PIL add text on top of images"

first result: http://python-catalin.blogspot.com/2010/06/add-text-on-image-with-pil-module.html

anyway, if you're looking for the library, you want to check into [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

Comment: accept the answer then, please :) Have fun with your project, too!

Answer (score 3):

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) can do that (it's the standard image processing library for Python anyway).